# Numpy: Find the values of rows given an array of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D array of values and a 1D array of indexes. I want to pull the values from the index of each row using an array of indexes. The following code would do this successfully:

```
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np
_2Darray = np.arange(100, dtype = np.float16)
_2Darray = _2Darray.reshape((10, 10))
array_indexes = [5,5,5,4,4,4,6,6,6,8]
index_values = []
for row, index in enumerate(array_indexes):
    index_values.append(_2Darray[row, index])
pprint(_2Darray)
print index_values
```

Returns

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.],
       [ 30.,  31.,  32.,  33.,  34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.],
       [ 40.,  41.,  42.,  43.,  44.,  45.,  46.,  47.,  48.,  49.],
       [ 50.,  51.,  52.,  53.,  54.,  55.,  56.,  57.,  58.,  59.],
       [ 60.,  61.,  62.,  63.,  64.,  65.,  66.,  67.,  68.,  69.],
       [ 70.,  71.,  72.,  73.,  74.,  75.,  76.,  77.,  78.,  79.],
       [ 80.,  81.,  82.,  83.,  84.,  85.,  86.,  87.,  88.,  89.],
       [ 90.,  91.,  92.,  93.,  94.,  95.,  96.,  97.,  98.,  99.]], dtype=float16)
[5.0, 15.0, 25.0, 34.0, 44.0, 54.0, 66.0, 76.0, 86.0, 98.0]
```

But I want to do it using only numpy functions. I have tried a whole bunch of numpy functions, but none of them seem to do this fairly simply task.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**
I managed to figure out what my implementation would be:
V_high = np.fromiter((

```
index_values = _2Darray[ind[0], ind[1]] for ind in
                    enumerate(array_indexes)),
                    dtype = _2Darray.dtype,
                    count = len(_2Darray))
```

Thanks to root I've got both implementations worked out. Now for some profiling:
My implementation run through cProfiler

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    2    0.274    0.137    0.622    0.311 {numpy.core.multiarray.fromiter}
20274    0.259    0.000    0.259    0.000 lazer_np.py:86(<genexpr>)
```

And root's:

```
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
```

**I can't believe it, but the cProfiler is not detecting root's method to take any time at all. I think this must be some kind of bug, but it is definitely noticeably faster. On an earlier test I got root's to be about 3 times faster**

Note: these tests were done on a shape = (20273, 200) array of np.float16 values. Additionally, each indexing had to be run twice for each test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
row = numpy.arange(_2Darray.shape[0])
index_values = _2Darray[row, array_indexes]
```

Numpy allows you to index 2d arrays (or nd arrays really) with two arrays such that:

```
for i in range(len(row)):
    result1[i] = array[row[i], col[i]]

result2 = array[row, col]
numpy.all(result1 == result2)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [15]: _2Darray[np.arange(len(_2Darray)), [5,5,5,4,4,4,6,6,6,8]]
Out[15]: array([  5.,  15.,  25.,  34.,  44.,  54.,  66.,  76.,  86.,  98.],
         dtype=float16)
```

BUT, I think something based on you solution may actually be the faster on smaller arrays. If the arrays are bigger than `100*100` use `numpy` indexing.

```
In [22]: def f(array, indices):
    ...:     return [array[row, index] for row, index in enumerate(indices)]

In [23]: f(_2Darray, [5,5,5,4,4,4,6,6,6,8])
Out[23]: [5.0, 15.0, 25.0, 34.0, 44.0, 54.0, 66.0, 76.0, 86.0, 98.0]
```

---

```
In [27]: %timeit f(_2Darray,[5,5,5,4,4,4,6,6,6,8])
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.48 us per loop

In [28]: %timeit _2Darray[np.arange(len(_2Darray)), [5,5,5,4,4,4,6,6,6,8]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.2 us per loop
```

Comment: These timings seem premature and without knowing more specifics about the OPs use-case they are not very useful. In general, using numpy's indexing and passing arrays (note you used lists above) is going to give the best performance.

Comment: @BiRico -- I did the timings again, and it seems that the list comprehension is faster with arrays smaller than `100*100`...changed the wording...also note that `len(array)` is faster than `array.shape[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay attention to use specifically numpy functions designed for **arrays**, **not** for **matrixes**. The two are easy to confuse and do not raise error when methods of one are called on the other, yet the output is pretty much unpredicatable.